# Can someone please help my with my ActionScript 3.0 Class

Tags: actionscript

I've been having quite a bit of difficulty trying to get my class working and no matter how much I change it I keep getting errors. The current error I'm getting is 'An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: PlayerPic, arrowMove'

Code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class PlayerPic extends MovieClip {
        public function PlayerPic()}

        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, arrowMove)
            // constructor code
            trace ("PlayerPic Constructer")}



    function arrowMove(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            pp.x -= 5;
            if (pp.x < 0)
        {
           pp.x = 0;
        }
        }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            pp.x += 5;
            if (pp.x > 250)
        {
            pp.x = 250;
        }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            pp.y -= 5;
            if (pp.y < 0)
        {
            pp.y = 0;
        }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            pp.y += 5;
        if (pp.y > 550)
        {
           pp.y = 550;
        }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
public function PlayerPic()}
```

To this:

```
public function PlayerPic()
```